# Set a specific name to a pod created from a yaml with an apply command

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I would like to know if there is a way to launch a pod from a yaml but with a custom name.

The objective of all this is to be able to add to the pod name something like a user id and then be able to delete it when the user requires it, having this way an unequivocal way to find the pod.

It would be something like:

```
kubectl apply -f ./foo.yaml -name custom-name
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nice! -1 for ask a valid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with `kubectl`, but you can:

- Perform the substitution with something like `sed` and pipe the result to `kubectl apply`:

  ```
  sed 's/PODNAME/custom-name/' foo.yaml |
    kubectl apply -f-
  ```

  (This assumes that you have `name: PODNAME` in the original manifest.)
- Use a YAML processing tool to make the change. For example, using [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) (note that there are multiple commands with that name; hence the link).

  ```
  yq '.metadata.name = "custom-name"' foo.yaml |
    kubectl apply -f-
  ```

  This has the advantage that you don't need a specific sentinel name like `PODNAME` in the source file.
- Create a Helm template and deploy the manifest(s) with `helm`, in which case you could set the value on the command line.

  ```
  helm install <your/repository> --set-string podname=custom-name
  ```
- Use some other templating tool, such as Ansible's [`k8s` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_module.html).